# IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0 SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /worklightconsole has not been defined

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I tried to install MobileFirst Operation Console in a clustered environment. WAS01 and WAS02.

After deployed the MobileFirst Operational console tried to access the console. Got the below error. Checked the Virtual host settings in both Cluster Member. its set to default_host.

```
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /worklightconsole has not been defined.
```

- WAS 8.5.5 FixPack 3
- DB2 10.1 Fixpack 3
- MobileFirst Platform Foundation consumer edition 7.0

Comment: Please add full messages.log files from both servers as well as server.xml

Comment: Thanks Idan and Bruno. I created a new Virtual Host and added the following ports of WAS Cluster Member to the alias WC_defaulthost, WC_defaulthost_secure, SIP_DEFAULTHOST , SIP_DEFAULTHOST_SECURE, 80 and 443. And changed the Applications virtual host to the new one, restarted the server and node agent. Now its working fine. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message is emitted by the WAS Web container. You have to check that :

1) worklightconsole is the right context root for the MFP console application

2) The hostname and port used to connect the console are correctly defined in the default_host virtual host

Comment: Hi Bruno, IBM PMR L3 Support helped to resolve this issue. As i have a Clustered topology and both my WAS01 and WAS02 servers in a private LAN, its not able to ping the Operation Console admin services. So we created JVM process definition custom property entries for hostname and port in both Cluster Members with the internal IP / URL. Then its started working fine. This procedure is no were documented in Info Center. Thanks Again.